# awaiting a value from a async function with setTimeOut and Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So I have this famous function from the documentation.

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

How should I rewrite it so when I type console.log(resolveAfter2Seconds(10)) I would get a result not Promise {Pending} in the console? The first bit is probably easy - putting async in front. But what next?

Answer (score 0):

dont you need

```
resolveAfter2Seconds(1).then(c=>console.log(c))
```

Comment: According to the requirement provided to me I have to use async/await.

Comment: ```(async ()=>{
  let c =await resolveAfter2Seconds(34)
  console.log(c)})()```

Comment: Thanks, I came up with something similar 
`async function msg() {
  const msg = await ResolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log('Message:', msg);
}

msg(); `

Comment: yes you used named function. but why did you use the same name for function and variable .thanks